# How to append straight markup to HEAD without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string containing HTML for stylesheets (created via the Rails asset pipeline), and I need to append this to the head and have the stylesheets actually load, in all major browsers. The string looks like this:

```
<link href="https://www.v.me/assets/core-28020ec7a202f8bc47a5d70d5aeb8477.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://www.v.me/assets/widgets-d4c93376a05ffe6d726371b89bc58731.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://www.v.me/assets/flowplayer-minimalist-3254ab41f4865c79282728f0012bb98d.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://www.v.me/assets/main-12765c4980ba6d109852c52830b34586.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I need to do this without using jQuery. Is this possible?

I wish I had the URLs in an array, but I don't. As a last resort, I could consider using a regex to parse out the URLs, but I'd like to avoid this.

Comment: jQuery is just a framework layer based in javascript.  Anything you can do in jQuery, you can do in javascript, albeit being a bit more cumbersome.

Comment: That's true. I should have worded that part of the question differently. Yay for end-of-day Friday questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
function addLink(linkURL,rel,type,media){
   var link = document.createElement('link');
   link.href = linkURL;
   link.rel = rel? rel: 'stylesheet';
   link.media = media ? media: 'screen';
   link.type = type ? type: 'text/css';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(link, s)
}

addLink('https://www.v.me/assets/core-28020ec7a202f8bc47a5d70d5aeb8477.css')
```

There are few things which might be not obvious here, like inserting after the script tag instead of body or head. Refer [here](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/05/11/appendchild-vs-insertbefore/) for more information

Comment: This is the best method, IMO, but it needs the other parameters of `link` added such as `rel`, `type`, and `media` to be a complete solution :)

Comment: @CollinGrady Modified the code to accept the rel/type/media with suitable defaults.

Comment: This solution requires knowing the URLs, but the asker explicitly said *I could consider using a regex to parse out the URLs, but I'd like to avoid this*.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this won't work for my situation since I only have already-generated markup to deal with, but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
var pHead = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
pHead.innerHTML = pHead.innerHTML + assetsString;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
document.head.innerHTML +=
    '<link href="https://www.v.me/assets/core-28020ec7a202f8bc47a5d70d5aeb8477.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />'
    +'<link href="https://www.v.me/assets/widgets-d4c93376a05ffe6d726371b89bc58731.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />'
    +'<link href="https://www.v.me/assets/flowplayer-minimalist-3254ab41f4865c79282728f0012bb98d.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />'
    +'<link href="https://www.v.me/assets/main-12765c4980ba6d109852c52830b34586.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />'
;
```

For old browsers, first use

```
if(!document.head) document.head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
```

---

**Edit**: @Sriharsha warned that the code above could download again all the resources. That doesn't happen on Firefox 27, but if you want to avoid this for sure, you could use:

```
var tmpHead = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument().head;
tmpHead.innerHTML = myString;
for (var i=0, tmpLink; tmpLink = tmpHead.childNodes[i]; ++i) {
    document.head.appendChild( tmpLink.cloneNode(false) );
}
```

Note that `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument` only works on new browsers.

Comment: This is a crude method, if you set the innerHTML like this, it will download all the resources(styles/scripts..) again even if its already available.

Comment: @Sriharsha That doesn't happen on FF27. Anyway, I have updated my answer with an alternative code which avoids this problem for sure.

Answer (score 2):

If `CSSTags` is a string containing the HTML for all your link tags then you can use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML += CSSTags;
```